# c# preloading modules in splashscreen

Tags: c#-4.0

I am developing a software with 3 modules in it. I want a splashscreen to be created in my project, which i want to preload all the modules before it shows the first form. Although the project is not too big, but still for an experience i want to add splashscreen in the current project with preloading ability.

I would like something like adobe Photoshop splashscreen does.

Any good tutorials/suggestions/videos are welcome keeping in mind i am not a C# pro coder and dont know much about the functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how the Photoshop splashscreen works.  However, to preload an assembly, it is enough to call the typeof(AnyTypeFromNonLoadedAssembly).  Hope, this helps.

Comment: can you please elaborate? as i said i am not a pro, so could not understand. Or any other detailed tutorial.

Comment: Your .NET application references some assemblies.  Right?  To load an assembly explicitly, you should call the typeof method and pass any type from this assembly as an argument.  That is all :)